# Julia/JuMP - Couenne: How to get intermediate or best feasible solutions when TIME_LIMIT has been reached?

Tags: julia-jump

I am running MINLP solver Couenne in Julia/JuMP and could not get the best feasible solutions out. Any help is appreciated.

I set up time_limit=60 in couenne.opt under the work directory as

```
time_limit 60
allowable_gap 1
allowable_fraction_gap 0.0001
feas_tolerance 0.0001
```

However, when the 60 seconds time_limit has been reached, the statuses are:

```
primal_status(model)=FEASIBLE_POINT

termination_status(model)=LOCALLY_SOLVED
```

But the issue is that the decision variables are 0 and objective is 0, basically null or empty.

I am using

```
using AmplNLWriter, Couenne_jll

model = Model(() -> AmplNLWriter.Optimizer(Couenne_jll.amplexe))
```

Attached is the output

```
Couenne 0.5.8 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization
Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne
couenne: 
ANALYSIS TEST: Reformulating problem: 11.8 seconds
NLP0012I 
              Num      Status      Obj             It       time                 Location
NLP0014I             1         OPT -0.39672801       76 6.214076
NLP0014I             2        TIME 0        2 0.102525
Loaded instance "/var/folders/sx/gcm0k6yd7fng162n002d7h440000gp/T/jl_Fz3AVB/model.nl"
Constraints:           82
Variables:           1375 (1291 integer)
Auxiliaries:           38 (4 integer)

Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -3687.1319
Clp0032I Optimal objective -3687.13193 - 0 iterations time 0.002
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -3687.1319
Cbc0004I Integer solution of -3687.1319 found after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.01 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -3687.131929999996, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.01 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -3687.1319

        "Finished"

Linearization cuts added at root node:          0
Linearization cuts added in total:              0  (separation time: 0s)
Total solve time:                        0.012623s (0.012624s in branch-and-bound)
Lower bound:                             -3687.13
Upper bound:                             -3687.13  (gap: 0.00%)
Branch-and-bound nodes:                         0
Performance of                           FBBT:      0.01599s,        1 runs. fix:          0 shrnk:     1172.2 ubd:          0 2ubd:          2 infeas:          0
*****************************
primal_status=FEASIBLE_POINT
termination_status=LOCALLY_SOLVED
Solution Status is local optimal solution
Objective Value:0.0

Solution for Decision Variables:
[0, 0, ..., 0]
```

I tried another MINLP solver SCIP in Julia/JuMP for the same optimization problem. It is able to send back the intermediate best feasible solutions when time_limit =60 has been reached.

Comment: Also asked here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/getting-output-after-solver-timeout-reached/81324/5. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Oscar: Thank you for your reply. My code involves thousands of integer variables and loading external data. I will work on creating a small sample problem, reproducing this scenario.

Comment: I am trying to upload nl file here but the file is too long

Comment: Oscar: Thanks for having investigated this issue and identified this issue as couenne bug in https://github.com/jump-dev/AmplNLWriter.jl/issues/160